# Trying to install OpenCPU on CentOS 7 server running WHM & CloudLinux

Tags: centos7, whm, opencpu

I'm trying to run OpenCPU on a CentOS 7 dedicated server that is already running WHM and CloudLinux.

The first step was to install dependencies :

```
yum install rpm-build make wget tar httpd-devel libapreq2-devel R-devel libcurl-devel protobuf-devel openssl-devel libxml2-devel libicu-devel libssh2-devel
```

One of the requirements of OpenCPU installation is "libapreq2-devel" which depends on "httpd-mmn" :

```
Error: Package: libapreq2-2.13-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           **Requires: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664**
Error: Package: libapreq2-devel-2.13-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           **Requires: httpd-devel >= 2.0.48**

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

After I removed temporarily "httpd*" from the exclude list of yum configuration file (etc/yum.conf) and tried the command above again, I got this new error :

```
Error: **ea-apache24 conflicts with httpd-2.4.6-90.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64**

Error: Package: libapreq2-devel-2.13-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           **Requires: httpd-devel >= 2.0.48**
           Available: httpd-devel-2.4.6-18.el7_0.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)

httpd-devel = 2.4.6-18.el7_0.cloudlinux
           Available: httpd-devel-2.4.6-30.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)

httpd-devel = 2.4.6-30.el7.cloudlinux
           Available: httpd-devel-2.4.6-31.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 

...

...

(cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
               httpd-devel = 2.4.6-90.el7.cloudlinux

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Before digging deeper, anyone tried to do the same and run OpenCPU alongside WHM installation ? And would that be a reliable solution to run on a production environment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you did, but maybe you can see how the [centos 7 docker image](https://github.com/opencpu/opencpu-server/blob/master/docker/centos-7/Dockerfile) does it:

```
docker run -it opencpu/centos-7
```

If you install the opencpu-server [precompiled binaries](http://archive.opencpu.org/) you don't need these `-devel` packages.

Comment: Still getting the same error at the installation step of the dependency "libapreq2-devel". Please note that the real problem is a conflict with WHM and/or CloudLinux and I'm lokking for a workaround.

Comment: It seems cloudlinux ships a version of httpd that conflicts with EPEL? But maybe you can avoid the problem by installing the precompiled binaries for opencpu, so that you don't need the `-devel` packages: http://archive.opencpu.org/

Comment: Hi @Jeroen, yes that's right there is obviously a conflict out there. I tried installing the precompiled binaries but still the same. Even the binary of "opencpu-server" is requesting the binary of "rapache" which is requesting again the "libapreq2" library.

Comment: And by the way, Docker is not an option neither. Docker will not run on CloudLinux due to a different kernel design, and there are no plans to support it.